# Working with Emailing using templates

Tags: email, azure, xslt, json.net, azure-functions

We are building an Azure Function which is a timer based function. The responsibility of the function is to pick messages from the Service Bus Topic and send out an email to end user. I know we can maintain email templates using xslt templates and can transform and form the email message. Is there any way using json to create an email message with the help of a template?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at nuget or npm to see if there is a package that does what you need, for example:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/email-templates

The sendgrid output binding may also provide some of what you need:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-sendgrid